# Error: Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses. On Sub select

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I am trying to use the row number in sub query to bring values from another table part of my stored procedure is as below. Error is on the sub query:

```
;with cte as
(
    select 
        @sDate StartDate, 
        DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk, 0, @sDate),7) EndDate  

    union all

    select  
        dateadd(d, 1, EndDate),
        dateadd(ww, 1, dateadd(ww, 1, StartDate)) 
    from 
        cte
    where 
        dateadd(wk, 1, StartDate) <=  @eDate
), cte2 as 
(
    select 
        *, 
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER by iD)) as rn 
    from 
        [KFC].[dbo].[tblCOMPANYTAXPERIOD] 
    where 
        [COMPANYTAXYEARID] = 4 
)
select  
    REPLICATE('0', 3 - LEN(RTRIM(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER by EndDate)))) + RTRIM(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER by EndDate)) AS [PAYROLLRUNNUMBER],
    (CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), StartDate, 106)) as PERIODSTARTDATE,    
    (CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), EndDate, 106)) as PERIODENDDATE, 
    (select iD 
     from cte2 
     where [COMPANYTAXYEARID] = 4 
       and [TAXPERIODNO] = rn) AS [COMPANYTAXPERIODID]  
from 
    cte c
```

Error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cte for that, try something like this: Windowing function is not allowed in where clause

```
;with cte as
(
  select @sDate StartDate, DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk, 0, @sDate),7) EndDate --, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER by @sDate) as  number
  union all
  select  dateadd(d, 1, EndDate),
    dateadd(ww, 1, dateadd(ww, 1, StartDate))--,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER by EndDate) as  number
  from cte
  where dateadd(wk, 1, StartDate)<=  @eDate
), cte2 as 
( select iD, [TAXPERIODNO], (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER by EndDate)) as rn from [KFC].[dbo].[tblCOMPANYTAXPERIOD] where [COMPANYTAXYEARID] = 4 )
--Insert Into #Temp select * from cte 
select  REPLICATE('0',3-LEN(RTRIM( ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER by EndDate)))) + RTRIM(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER by EndDate)) as [PAYROLLRUNNUMBER]
,  (CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),StartDate,106)) as PERIODSTARTDATE, (CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),EndDate,106)) as PERIODENDDATE  
,   (select iD from cte2 where  [TAXPERIODNO] =rn )as  [COMPANYTAXPERIODID]  from cte c
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance .  cte2  is giving an error - Invalid column name 'EndDate'.When i  changed it to ID .  error changed to **Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.**

Comment: Is there a way of using the row number of cte when querying  cte2. in this case Cte has 53 rows and cte2 has only 12 rows

Comment: Can you place the changed code? I am not getting you the error

Comment: Looks like 'select iD from cte2 where [COMPANYTAXYEARID] = 4 and [TAXPERIODNO] =rn ' statement returning more than one record, Can you explain bit more on this logic?

Comment: cte contains 52/53  rows . each row represents the start and end of a week in a financial year. cte2/tblCOMPANYTAXPERIOD(Contains more than one financial year hence the use of COMPANYTAXYEARID ) contains financial periods 1 - 12 (months/taxperiodno) each of the 52/53 rows must have a month or taxperiodno that they falls in.